# Real-time linting of Python with VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

Recently I'm using VSCode as my Python IDE, and I install
[DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode), which supports linting. However, the linter only works when saving, but what I want is *real-time linting*. [The workaround](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Linting#lint-as-you-type) suggested by the author is to set `files.autoSave` to `on`, so that the linter will work whenever the file is automatically saved. There's a [relevant discussion on Github](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/134), for your reference.

Since I don't want to turn on auto-save function, is there any way to do *real-time linting* of Python with VSCode? Or is there any suggested extension?

Comment: answer was received here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53597752/visual-studio-code-can-you-have-real-time-linting-for-python

Answer (score 0):

If you use shift + cmd + P (or ^+ctrl+P for windows) or go to View > Command Palette and type "Lint"

The Command Palette allows you to execute different commands, from here you can enable/disable Linting and select which Linter you would like to use. Most popular is PyLint but you can select Flake8 or Pep8 or whatever you like.

I believe you need to do these things before the linter works in real-time.

To scan for problems with your code without saving first, use shift + cmd + M, you will receive an error code in the vscode Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT2, 27 Mar 2024**

Just only use this config to real time linting.

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

My installed extensions are

- python
- pylint
- pylance
- python debugger
- autopep8

---

**EDIT1**
Update 4 Jul 2022
New version of python extension deprecates `"python.pythonPath"` and suggest to use this instead.

```
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
```

Put these lines in `.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

And install `autopep8` package.

Use pip to install it

`python3 -m pip install autopep8`

Or in Debian based as `python3-autopep8` exists in repo you can run

`sudo apt install python3-autopep8`

And then python linting on vscode will work.

Also, the Warning menu will activate.

Hint that I set run linter onsave.
[image: warning]