# Visual Studio Code - Can you have real-time linting for python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

There is the same exact question here, but there hasn't been any replies.

[Real-time linting of Python with VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43755339/real-time-linting-of-python-with-vscode)

I'm using the Python extension right now that is on the VS code marketplace.

After about an hour of research, I found the following option in the linter:

```
python.linting.lintOnSave
```

I set it to false, but that just pretty much just disables linting. There has to be a way if auto complete works in real-time.

Is it possible to have linting done in real-time in VS code? As of right now, the linting only works when I save. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need `python.linting.pylintEnabled` and make sure `pylint` is installed.

Comment: Is it possible to see the ratings generated by pylint real time in vs code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please a have look at [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/28) post. There was already a feature called `lintOnTextChange`, but it is deprecated now. You have to extend your config file with the following lines to get it work on text change:

```
"python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
"files.autoSave": true
```

But this is more a workaround, instead of a proper solution for your problem.
Also have a look at [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/313).

Comment: You're the best. I had to edit it a bit. The files.autoSave feature changed a bit. It no longer takes true/false but takes strings to set it to certain modes. Here was the Code: {
    "python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 500
}

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are after from linting. If you want a specific linter to run constantly then the answer provided by @benni94 is accurate. But if you're simply after things like syntax errors then using the langauge server will provide this (set `"python.jediEnabled": false` in your settings to turn it on).