# Linting in Visual Studio Code Python stymies real time error detection

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, lint, pylint, python-extensions

I've used other editors (Spyder) where linting is real time, and it's incredibly useful to **catch coding errors in real time**. I'm not necessarily looking for real time, but even after I save, I have to wait 30 seconds or so.

I've seen this issue floating around, eg [Visual Studio Code - Can you have real-time linting for python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53597752/visual-studio-code-can-you-have-real-time-linting-for-python) and I've tried changing

```
"python.jediEnabled": false
```

in my settings, with no effect.

I've also looked at where the issue is arising, and I don't think it's pylint, eg https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/444

I wonder if the issue is originating in the Python extension, or VSC, or both.

Is there a simple fix? If so can someone show me? Or is this really an issue that to my eyes seems like it's been swept under the rug.

Seems like an incredibly useful feature and frankly I'm mystified why such an amazing IDE like VSC is missing what I would humbly consider to be such an epic feature.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `"python.jediEnabled": false` will give you linting as you type, but you didn't specify what you meant by "linting" to know if that's what you're after. For instance, syntax errors will be highlighted, but if you're looking for e.g. flake8 to be run in real-time then that is not supported at the moment. If you want that sort of support then please  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/408.